# Развертывание приложения на node.js в локальной сети

Tags: node.js, nginx

Есть приложение реализованное на *node.js* представляющее из себя *REST API* + клиент для него с использованием *backbone.js*. Приложение будет использоваться только в рамках локальной сети. Насколько целесообразно развертывание с использованием *nginx/apache*?. Пользователей работающих с приложением будет не больше 200. Штатные средства *node.js* должны же справится с такой нагрузкой?

Comment: а как ты видишь использование nginx или apache? какие задачи могли бы решаться с их помощью?

Comment: балансировка нагрузки как вариант, оформление "нормальных" ссылок - например http://application1/ http://application2. Все это что бы "висело" на порту по умолчанию (80) которым бы управлял nginx проксируя запросы уже в соответствии с настроенными конфигурациями. Ну и во многих мануалах поднимается этот вопрос, так что я решил для начала прощупать почву.

Comment: _балансировка_: ты собираешься поднять несколько экземпляров ноды и между ними балансировать? _нормальные ссылки_: почему бы сразу не сделать нормальные роутеры? _80 порт_ может слушать и нода. если только эти задачи (rest api) то nginx - просто лишняя сущность. но, может, есть что-то о чем ты не пишешь: статика, кеширование и т.д.?

Comment: все верно, несколько экземпляров ноды и между ними балансировать, вопросы о статике и кешировании даже не возникали пока что и потому я не рассматриваю их, просто в основном волнует вопрос использования штатного веб сервера, к примеру в тех же _RoR/Django/Mojolicious_ штатные вебсерверы как правило однопоточные и предназначены в основном для тестирования и разработки.

Comment: для обрабатывания запросов в несколько потоков можно взять cluster. nginx/apache, судя по всему, тут ничего не улучшат.

Comment: в общих чертах ситуация прояснилась)) спасибо